# For Azure Function App scaling, will all active nodes be triggered or just one of them?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am designing a solution that includes an Azure Function App function that will be triggered when a blob is created in an Azure Blob Storage container. The Function App will automatically scale out when needed (more than one instance will be available, pre-warmed). If there are two or more nodes active at a specific moment, and a new blob is created, **will the function be triggered**:

a. For each of the nodes

or

b. For only one of the available free instances (and just one)

Comment: The Function will scale For each of the nodes, Refer this github link on scaling function app for consumption and premium plan - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling.md

Comment: In the Consumption and Premium plans, Azure Functions scales CPU and memory resources by adding more instances of the Functions host. The number of instances is determined on the number of events that trigger a function.

Each instance of the Functions host in the Consumption plan is limited, typically to 1.5 GB of memory and one CPU. An instance of the host is the entire function app, meaning all functions within a function app share resource within an instance and scale at the same time. Function apps that share the same Consumption plan scale independently

Comment: Only one function instance will process the blob if that is what you really want to know.

Comment: @PeterBons, yes, let's say I have three instances active, I want to make sure the function will not be triggered three times, alas, I don't want the same file to be processed three times. If it is as you explained, do you have any link to where this is mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-concurrency) and this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-concurrency) explain how Azure uses an internal queueing for events and process each of them using an instance if available, or creating a new one if needed. So answer is, **Function is triggered only once per triggering event for any kind of trigger (i.e. blob creation or update, HTTP request, service bus queue or topic message)**.

Since Azure will not process the same file using multiple instances, for that kind of requirement the [fan in fan out pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp) must be used.

Comment: The concurrency mentioned in the linked articles describe how concurrent function invocations are dealt with regarding scaling the number of messages received in a function invocation and how many invocations can run concurrently. That does not guarantee an exactly-once-delivery mechanism. That's why for blobs blob receipts are used for example.

Answer (score 0):

Only one function instance will process the blob if that is what you really want to know

> yes, let's say I have three instances active, I want to make sure the function will not be triggered three times, alas, I don't want the same file to be processed three times. If it is as you explained, do you have any link to where this is mentioned?

Well, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#blob-receipts):

> The Azure Functions runtime ensures that no blob trigger function gets called more than once for the same new or updated blob. To determine if a given blob version has been processed, it maintains blob receipts.

If you are using the Event Grid to handle blob events things are different as the Event Grid service is responsible for sending events to a Event Grid triggered Azure Function. The function will always react to each event grid event once, but do mind that the Event Grid is designed using a *at-least-once* delivery mechanism:

> Event Grid provides durable delivery. It tries to deliver each message at least once for each matching subscription immediately.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry))

Comment: "The Azure Functions runtime ensures that no blob trigger function gets called more than once for the same new or updated blob". I would interpret this as this mechanism guarantees than no more than one function consumes the blob event. My question is more about the instances of a function, and at the end for any trigger in general (i.e. an HTTP request, a message available for peeking in a service bus queue, etc.). Will the trigger be called for all the instances, or just for one of the available ones? The articles I found seem to show it is just for one instance, for any kind of trigger.

Comment: It will be triggered for just one function instance. The reason that it is not stated that specific in the docs is due to the fact that the infrastructure details are not something the consumer needs to think about , it is abstracted away.